# What kind of Markup should i use for the Notes in my WebApp?

Tags: wysiwyg, markup

i am building a webapp that will have notes fields all over the place, but i dont know what kind of markup i should use.

these are my requirements

- User must be able to change the text style (bold, italic, underlined)
- User must be able to create bullet lists
- User must be able to create numbered lists
- User must be able to change the font-size or use pre-definded headings
- User must be able to add links
- User must have a WYSIWYG - Editor that hides the actual markup

the last one is the most important requirement, my target users struggle even with word, so using markup style input like here on stackoverflow is not an option.

so what kind`s of markup do you know that fits ans has some fancy WYSIWYG - Editor?
if you think that i missed a important requirement please feel free to suggest it.

tia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to check out [tinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).

It's the best javascript-based WYSIWYG editor I've found.